# Scrollview scrolling below CollapsingToolbarLayout due to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a detail activity that show the details of a game in my app. The layout is composed mainly by a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the game cover and a `NestedScrollView` containing the details. The layout is like this:
[image: 1]
And scrolled like this:
[image: 2]
The XML files for the layout are:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_detail_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.GameDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/game_cover"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_game_detail" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the `content_game_detail` is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_detail_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.GameDetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game_detail">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- There are 11 TextViews here for all the info -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/videos_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/simple_margin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videos_lable" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The problem is: when the summary is very long and there are videos to add items to the `RecyclerView`, the layout start a little scrolled below the expanded toolbar like this:

[image: 3]

I need to scroll the view back down to see the top of the information. Testing, I narrowed down the problem to the `RecyclerView`. When I remove it, this problem doesn't happen. It seems that when the items are added to the `RecyclerView`, the layout scroll itself up to compensate, but I couldn't found why this happens (instead of just expand the view down) nor how to solve it. Does anyone have any idea?